# How to use GLKMatrixStack?

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, objective-c++, glkit

I'm writing an iOS game that draws many cubes on screen, but I have a problem with positioning the cubes.

I have a function `draw_voxel` that draws a cube:

```
void draw_voxel(Point location, Color color, GLKMatrixStackRef stack) {
  GLKMatrixStackPush(stack);
  GLKMatrixStackTranslate(stack, location.x, location.y, location.z);

  std::array<Color, 36> triangle_colors;
  triangle_colors.fill(color);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
  glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, static_cast<const GLvoid*>(triangle_vertices.data()));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
  glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, static_cast<const GLvoid*>(triangle_colors.data()));
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);

  GLKMatrixStackPop(stack);
}
```

I pass it a `GLKMatrixStackRef`, push the current matrix on top and use `GLKMatrixStackTranslate` to translate the top matrix. However, all cubes are still drawn at (0, 0, 0).

I call `draw_voxel` like this:

```
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

GLKMatrixStackRef stack = GLKMatrixStackCreate(nullptr);
draw_voxel(Point(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), stack);
draw_voxel(Point(+0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), stack);
draw_voxel(Point(+1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), stack);
CFRelease(stack);
```

I couldn't find any useful information on the internet about GLKit matrix stacks, and I'm really stuck. How do I "apply" the top matrix so that the cubes are translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still haven't fully grasp how to use GLKMatrixStack, looking at your code I think the problem is that you are not passing the top matrix of the stack to the shader, or, in GLKit words, you are not properly configuring the effect.
Probably, at some point you should be doing something like:

```
self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrixStackGetMatrix4(stack);
```

Hope this help, I'm stuck on that stack too :)

Comment: And then just send `-prepareToDraw`, and after popping the stack do the same, right? I just have to pass the effect to `draw_voxel` as an argument.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. You create a new stack at each rendering pass, and then use it to calculate a single translation and just pop the top matrix. As far as I understand, matrix stacks are useful in hierarchical animation systems. Probably you can just obtain the `GLKMatrix4` you need through a `GLKMatrix4MakeTranslate` call.